# Should "person" be replaced with "a person" or "the person" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles

In our European company we’re just working on our new identity cards and we need your help :-). There must be an important text on the ID cards, which says to everyone, that an employee (ID owner) is really from our company... The idea of the board of directors is:

> **“This is to certify that person, whose signature and photograph appear hereon, is an employee of COMPANY-NAME.”**

(Person’s name, photo and signature is placed above this text.)

Please – is that correct?

I’m in a doubt – may I use “person”, “a person” or “the person”?

Please help. We don’t want to look like a fools after creating hundreds of cards :-).

Comment: Try "This is to certify that the person whose signature ... "(include a definite article and drop the comma after "person").

Comment: If I saw that text I would assume/hope that the actual name of the person would be substituted for "person" when the card is produced.

Comment: Hi Martin. If you haven't yet done so, please take the site [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the Help Center page "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" Generalized proofreading questions like "Please check the correctness of the sentence" are not on-topic for this site. I have edited your question to replace that title with a title focused on the specific issue you brought up in the body of your question: the choice of article with the word "person".

Comment: Would the purpose of the card not be obvious without the text?

Comment: I would go with "that person"

Comment: Note that the commas don't make sense if "the person" is used.

Comment: Remove the text completely.  I’ve never seen a badge with text like that.  Or just put **EMPLOYEE** Also suggest you remove the job title or else you’ll be replacing badges whenever people move within the company.

Answer (score 1):

"... the person ..."

If it said "**a** person" it would imply that there may be more than one person with the same signature and photograph and that one of them is an employee.  This is probably the exact opposite of what you what to say on an ID card.

Answer (score 0):

“This is to certify that this person, whose signature and photograph appear hereon, is an employee of COMPANY-NAME.”

: )